# What exactly is on the Fed balance sheet?

Tags: federal-reserve, united-states

All the rage these days is how crazily big the Fed's balance sheet has grown. Looking on [federalreserve.gov](https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/bst_recenttrends.htm), I can see its value topped up ~6,573,136 millions USD (~6 trillion USD).

Fine, but is there an exhaustive list of all the assets on this balance sheet? Loans? Bonds? Cash? Equities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this federal Reserve webpage that provides links.](https://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/bst_fedsbalancesheet.htm)

Note that these are aggregates; there are specialised reports on various components of their balance sheets.

The FRED website has these series in an interactive database.